# Deleting data from SSAS within a time range using c#

Tags: c#, sql, ssas, mdx-query

I am trying to delete particular data in my SSAS database, e.g I have data for one month and I want to delete data for one day only within this month, how can I do it using MDX query or c#?

Note: I want to delete the day data from the database and not retrieve the data of the month without this day.

Answer (score 0):

If your measure group is partitioned by day, you can just drop that particular partition. I would recommend this.

Otherwise there is no option to delete rows from a measure group. You can ProcessAdd to insert new rows. Or you can ProcessFull to reload all rows (which effectively can delete a day of data if that day doesn't get returned anymore from the query). But there is no delete of rows.

This answer assumes an SSAS Multidimensional cube. The answer is the same for Tabular but I used Multidimensional terminology in the answer.